Why does Japanese not have a native "tu" sound?
I'm a relatively new learner of Japanese, and something that surprised me is that there's no "native" "tu" sound, it can be approximated in katakana with トゥ (in its place, Japanese has the "tsu" sound).
My curiosity is also piqued because I used to practice a form of karate-do that came from "Tumai-ti" (トゥマイティ)... which does have that sound. I checked a bit and it's a place in Okinawa, but I see the common spelling is "Tomari-te", 泊手. So the Okinawan dialect did (does?) use the sound.

This video on the Okinawan language ウチナグチ. describes the differences in the sounds between Japanese & the language of Okinawa. They both came from a common parent but diverged to become almost unintelligible. Everyone in Okinawa speaks Japanese with Okinawa dialect words and pronunciation thrown in but native speakers of Okinawan are almost all over 80 years old with the language being mostly only preserved in the culture esp. in the realm of music. Understanding how the shifts occurred you can work out how to pronounce words in the Okinawan way https://youtu.be/V5Q1q6NFk4g?si=VI6YxoJRdiFogC6U

Simple answer is /tu/ turned into /tsu/ the same way /ti/ turned into /tʃi/ ('ti' turned into 'chi', basically). Phonemes are what we call phonetic units of meaningful distinction in languages, but each phoneme can be realized as various different sounds; different sounds under the same phoneme are allophones. In English, if you say 'pin', the P is aspirated, but not in 'spin', and yet many think of these as the same sound. But that difference of aspiration is phonemic in some languages, such as Hindi.
Influence of the following vowel causes the /t/ sound to undergo a slight change, but it didn't become phonemic until /tu/ was reborrowed from Western languages.
Okinawan has its own history where presumably this just didn't happen or it reacquired /tu/ in another way

Looks like Okinawan also "eliminated native tu" at some point (e.g. 鶴 Proto-Ryukyuan *turu > tsiru), but regained it from the change o -> u (as also shown by the example in the OP, *to > tu)

@qrsngky — Since "native tu" is still reflected in Okinawan, it's not really accurate to say that this was "eliminated", which implies that it is gone entirely. I'd say instead that "native /tu/ in Okinawan shifted to /ti/", as we see in modern words that have つ in Japanese and ち in Okinawan, like JA つとめる → RYU チトゥミユン. Whether that was before or after /tu/ affricated to /tsu/, I cannot say. Modern Okinawan トゥ /tu/ is a reflection of earlier /to/, another vowel sound shift.

@EiríkrÚtlendi I guess the change has been majorly attributed to affrication. I have explained in an answer. However, I did not find any native Japanese words containing /tu/ after exhaustive search.

@EirikrÚtlendi by "eliminated" I meant such a syllable was gone entirely from the vocabulary (i.e. no single word in that language used that syllable anymore). I didn't mean that "it disappeared without a trace". Rather, it was completely replaced by another thing.

I have extended @Eirikr's comment as an answer.
The change of "tu" to "tsu" can be attributed to stop/affricate system which refers to the tripartite contrast of alveolar stop [t], affricate [ts] and [t∫ ] in Modern Japanese. This development of alveolar stops and affricates goes well back to Late Old Japanese (the history is detailed in reference 1). The appearance of affricates in Japanese was due to an affrication process that affected palatalized syllables and alveolar stops before high front vowels i.e. [tj] -> [t∫], [ti] -> [t∫i], [tu] -> [tsu].
The process is as follows:

During the release phase of a stop, the air built up behind the closure escapes rapidly, within a few milliseconds. If the release is slower, the articulators spend more time in close proximity to each other, which prolongs the duration of the burst. A longer burst produces audible friction, which is perceptually identified as a fricative. Thus, insufficient coordination by the speaker results in a stop following by a fricative, that is, an affricate. The trajectories for tongue movement in [ti] and [ta] are represented schematically:


Later in Modern Japanese, /tu/(トゥ) were replaced with /tsu/(ツ) based on above system and as such, you won't find any native words containing "tu".

Even the loanwords containing explicit [tu] pronunciation is replaced with [tsu], for e.g. 'two -> /tsuu/, 'tour' -> /tsuaa/. In some cases, an innovative variant of [tu] is used, for e.g. 'Bantu' -> /bantuu/. The writing system encourages to use [tsu] and although many speakers can pronounce [tu], it is easier to fall back to more comfortable [tsu].
For more in-depth details, please read ref. 1
References

Handbook of Japanese Phonetics and Phonology by Haruo Kubozono,
Walter de Gruyter GmbH & Co KG, 2015
https://www.reddit.com/r/japanese/comments/194snhq/why_tu_and_not_tsu/
https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/11ika0p/tsu_vs_tu_for_foreign_words/
https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-no-ti-and-tu-in-the-Japanese-syllabary-figure
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%81%A4%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A8-read-as-ta-chi-tsu-te-to-and-not-ta-ti-tu-te-to


Minor quibble: You say, "/tu/(トゥ) were replaced with /tsu/(ツ)". It seems more accurate to say that "/tu/(トゥ) became /tsu/(ツ)", or "/tu/(トゥ) shifted to /tsu/(ツ)". This was a gradual process caused by the biomechanics of the shape of the mouth when making certain sounds, and we see analogues in languages around the word. Consider the /ʃ/ pronunciation of "ti" in modern English nation, for instance, as compared to the /ti/ in the original word in classical Latin [natio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/natio#Latin).

@EirikrÚtlendi I vaguely remember an article about language changes, showing that relatively sudden replacements are possible, (so a change is not necessarily gradual, as if "passing through every intermediate state in a continuum"). Whether such type of change is common, or whether such change was actually what happened in Japanese and Okinawan, is another question. (if I take examples from unrelated languages it would be off-topic here.)   But in the longer term, it makes no difference whether it's gradual or sudden, because the end result is the same, effectively a "replacement".

@qrsngky, thanks for the reply. I realized I didn't express my meaning well earlier: my quibble is about word choice, in that "replacement" implies intent. I wanted to stress that this was not an intentional change, but rather a natural evolution. By way of analogy, the pectoral and pelvic fins of lobe-finned fishes weren't "replaced" with arms and legs as tetrapods and later primates and humans evolved, as by some external actor causing the change, and instead these became arms and legs, as a spontaneous unintentional process. That said, this is but a minor quibble.
